# How do I get out of Provider Hell?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, sbt

I am trying to write some [Apache Spark code in Scala](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-frequent-pattern-mining.html), but I am stuck in 'Provider Hell'

```
import org.apache.spark
import org.apache.spark.ml.fpm.FPGrowth

@main def example1() = {
  println("Example 1")

  val dataset = spark.createDataset(Seq(
    "1 2 5",
    "1 2 3 5",
    "1 2")
  ).map(t => t.split(" ")).toDF("items")

  val fpGrowth = new FPGrowth().setItemsCol("items").setMinSupport(0.5).setMinConfidence(0.6)
  val model = fpGrowth.fit(dataset)

  // Display frequent itemsets.
  model.freqItemsets.show()

  // Display generated association rules.
  model.associationRules.show()

  // transform examines the input items against all the association rules and summarize the
  // consequents as prediction
  model.transform(dataset).show()
}
```

When I do try to compile this I get

```
sbt:fp-laboratory> compile
[info] compiling 2 Scala sources to /Users/eric.kolotyluk/git/autonomous-iam/poc/fp-laboratory/target/scala-3.1.2/classes ...
[error] -- [E008] Not Found Error: /Users/eric.kolotyluk/git/autonomous-iam/poc/fp-laboratory/src/main/scala/Example1.scala:7:22 
[error] 7 |  val dataset = spark.createDataset(Seq(
[error]   |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[error]   |                value createDataset is not a member of org.apache.spark
[error] one error found
[error] (Compile / compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 3 s, completed May 30, 2022, 2:13:18 PM
```

but this is not really the problem. IntelliJ complains about line 1 of my code `import org.apache.spark` highlighting `import` such that when I mouse over `import` I get

```
'/private/var/folders/h0/9w1gfn9j1qvgs5b_q9c16bj40000gp/T/fp-laboratory-fp-laboratory-target' does not exist or is not a directory or .jar file
```

which means absolutely nothing to me. I have no idea why it's looking for that. However, looking at my `build.sbt` file

```
ThisBuild / organization := "com.forgerock"
ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "3.1.2"
ThisBuild / version      := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "fp-laboratory",
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      ("org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % "3.2.1" % "provided").cross(CrossVersion.for3Use2_13),
      ("org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "3.2.0" % "provided").cross(CrossVersion.for3Use2_13)
   )
 )

// include the 'provided' Spark dependency on the classpath for `sbt run`
Compile / run := Defaults.runTask(Compile / fullClasspath, Compile / run / mainClass, Compile / run / runner).evaluated
```

When I remove `"provided"` from the build.sbt file, IntelliJ stops complaining about

'/private/var/folders/h0/9w1gfn9j1qvgs5b_q9c16bj40000gp/T/fp-laboratory-fp-laboratory-target' does not exist or is not a directory or .jar file

and only complains about `value createDataset is not a member of org.apache.spark`

***I suspect there is something fishy about `provided` scope, as until now, I have zero experience with this.***

Consequently, ***Provider Hell***.

My Scala code runs fine when I use

```
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/apache-spark/3.2.1/bin/spark-shell
```

So, I suspect there is some super secret magic required to run a Scala program under IntelliJ or SBT to say where `spark-mllib` and `spark-sql` are, but I am no wizard.

Can someone please tell me what the `provider` magic is so I can get out of hell.

Answer (score 2):

Well actually, that's not related to the `provider` scope. As you also mentioned, the code works fine when you use spark-shell, right? That's because in spark-shell, there's a predefined value named `spark`, which is an object of type `org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession`, and actually has a method called `createDataset`, but in your code in IntelliJ, the "spark" is referred to as `org.apache.spark` (imported right above), which is a package that does not have a method called `createDataset`. Do you see where I'm going? Try defining a variable of type `SparkSession` and use it in your code, something like this:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.ml.fpm.FPGrowth
org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

@main def example1() = {
  println("Example 1")

  val spark = SparkSession.builder()
    /* do your configurations here, like setting master, ... */
    .getOrCreate()

  val dataset = spark.createDataset(Seq(
    "1 2 5",
    "1 2 3 5",
    "1 2")
  ).map(t => t.split(" ")).toDF("items")

  // other stuff
}
```

Now this should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it was not Provider Hell, although I still don't understand this well, but I was not setting up my Spark app properly, as I did not realize that `spark-shell` automatically does a lot of work...

In my code I needed to explicitly create a SparkSession first...

```
def newSparkSession = SparkSession
  .builder
  .appName("Simple Application")
  .config("spark.master", "local")
  .getOrCreate()
```

then

```
Using(newSparkSession) { sparkSession =>

  import sparkSession.implicits._

  val dataset = sparkSession.createDataset(Seq(
    "1 2 5",
    "1 2 3 5",
    "1 2")
  ).map(t => t.split(" ")).toDF("items")

  val fpGrowth = new FPGrowth().setItemsCol("items").setMinSupport(0.5).setMinConfidence(0.6)
  val model = fpGrowth.fit(dataset)

  // Display frequent itemsets.
  model.freqItemsets.show()

  // Display generated association rules.
  model.associationRules.show()

  // transform examines the input items against all the association rules and summarize the
  // consequents as prediction
  model.transform(dataset).show()
}
```

Also, the correct build.sbt is

```
lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "fp-laboratory",
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      ("org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % "3.2.1" % "provided").cross(CrossVersion.for3Use2_13),
      ("org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql"   % "3.2.1" % "provided").cross(CrossVersion.for3Use2_13)
    ),
    Compile / run := Defaults.runTask(Compile / fullClasspath, Compile / run / mainClass, Compile / run / runner).evaluated
  )
```

Now I am onto my next Scala problem...